# Windows explorer freezing when selecting files in the Open file dialog

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, windows-explorer, freeze

I was trying to send some files, the browser opened the file explorer, which is alright, I navigated to the folder where the file was which was also fine. Then I selected the file to open (just selected, not actually opened), and the file explorer freoze.

It does the same both in chrome, firefox, and even discord, and crucially if I just use the windows explorer directly to open a file it works alright, it only happens when I'm trying to open a file with a different program.

Comment: "send some files," - How exactly?

Comment: Tried whatsapp web, tried email, the files where under 500 kb

Comment: How many files? This happening in all browsers seems to indicate a problem with the site, or the file system. Can you move the files to a different folder and see if you can then select and upload them?

Comment: one, as soon as I selected the first file the explorer froze

Comment: it hapens on multiple differrent folders, on multiple different programs,but I think it is specifically on pdf files

Comment: Even the open file dialog uses explorer shell extensions.  You have probably installed something that integrated with the shell to make this happen.  Try [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) utility to disable any "fishy" third party extensions from the shell.  Then reboot and try again.  Target the PDF stuff you mention in your comment first.

Comment: Thank you, Señor CMasMas, it worked